# To Date function not working with time stamp

Tags: oracle

To Date function not working I am not getting time stamp by using to date function through application. I am using the `FND_STANDERED_DATE_TIME` value set

I am using the code input `date:31-MAR-2017 17:50:24`

```
l_varchar := TO_DATE(P_FROM_DATE,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS');
v_P_from_date := fnd_date.canonical_to_date(l_varchar);
```

But I am getting only date as output `31-MAR-0017 00:00:00` I am submitting the program through backend I am not getting time stamp and year correctly

please correct me if I am wrong. please help me

Comment: `l_varchar := TO_DATE ...`? The function `TO_DATE` converts some string into a date, but you are assigning its result to a string. That makes no sense. So: what data type is your source `P_FROM_DATE`? what data type is your target `v_P_from_date`?

Comment: thanks for reply I have resolved the issue.

Comment: thanks for reply I have resolved the issue.                                          p_from_date is varchar2,  v_p_from_date is date,                              resolution I did was                                                                                            l_varchar := TO_DATE(P_FROM_DATE,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS');  l_varchar4:= to_char(l_varchar, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'); v_P_from_date := fnd_date.canonical_to_date(l_varchar4);

Answer (score 0):

It seems you get a string `p_from_date` which is formatted `'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'`. You want to get this into your date variable `v_p_from_date`. That would simply be:

```
v_p_from_date := TO_DATE(p_from_date, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS');
```